# Cannot create the new feed on Azure DevOps. Got an error "Cannot read property 'descriptor' of null"

Tags: azure-devops, artifacts

I have created a new organization and then trying to create a new feed on the Artifacts tab for packaging solution. But I cannot do it. I have got an error like "**Cannot read property 'descriptor' of null**" I'm not sure maybe I something missed in the permission or something like that. Could someone help me? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After creating the first pipeline with pack configuration the problem disappear